# Issue with parsing json into Python and filtering on key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, key

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. I'm relatively new to Python. I'm using an open Ergast API and am trying to import/parse a json file and filter on some of the elements. I can print the whole json file without issue, but as soon as I try to filter on driverId for example, it fails. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance:

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/current/last/results.json?")
data = response.json()
print (data["driverId"])
```

EDIT: the response I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
KeyError: 'driverId'
```

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error? If so you should post it.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm getting a key error on the print line for driverId. I know it's something I'm doing wrong as I've also tried the same with another api

Comment: so the error I get is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
KeyError: 'driverId'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key `driverId` is nested within array with `Results` which in turn is inside `Races` which in turn is inside `RaceTable` that is inside `MRData`. So to get the first driveId you'll have to use the following code

```
print(data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results'][0]['Driver']["driverId"])
```

If you want get all the values of `driverId` then you'll write a for loop

```
for driver in data['MRData']['RaceTable']['Races'][0]['Results']:
    print(driver['Driver']["driverId"])
```

Comment: Thanks so much Hari, that's my lack of knowledge on the json front. I'll mark it as the answer shortly :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but how would I loop this? I've tried but am failing terribly!

Comment: Thanks so much Hari, that's great.